# Is it possible to Kill Thread in Windows by "Start adress"?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, threads

I want to kill the Thread on startup. I am running windows 10. On every restart the thread ID (TID) changes, I can run "Proces Hacker" comand line utility, to kill Thread But It has new TID. I think the only way is to kill the Thrad by "Start Adress" - it's always same.
Does anybody has a solution for it?
P.S. I don't know C/C++. All I know is Batch Scripting and PowerShell.
Thank You

Comment: Play with something like `Get-Process -Name Notepad | Select -ExpandProperty Threads` or `Get-Process -Name Notepad | Select -ExpandProperty Threads | ? { $_.StartAddress -eq 140714396471472 }` and see if you can work it out. Otherwise maybe someone else can help you get the final result. In my case, I see multiple processes tied to that `StartAddress` property so not sure how to get the specific `ID` or TID you'd need from there without more testing.

Comment: I see `WaitReason` where one has a value of `UserRequest` so perhaps that's it but I don't have time to test more now. A quick idea for you or others if nothing else. You might be able to use WMI via PowerShell too if needed with quick example here perhaps: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-and-wmi-to-explore-threads/.